xml.etree.ElementTree. Element object has no attribute 'nsmap'
I try to process xml data from the website https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStR/Datendownload
I downloaded some datasets for a certain technology for example Netzanschlusspunkte. First step would be to delete certain columns. The second step would be to merge the files.
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os, psutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
path='....'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
if not filename.endswith('.xml'):continue
fullname = os.path.join(path,filename)
tree1 = ET.parse(fullname)
root1 = tree1.getroot()

path='....'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
if not filename.endswith('.xml'):continue
fullname = os.path.join(path,filename)
tree2 = ET.parse(fullname)
root2 = tree2.getroot()

names_to_delete = ['NetzanschlusspunktMastrNummer','LetzteAenderung']

for grandchild in list(root):
if grandchild.attrib in names_to_delete:
root.remove(grandchild)

def merge_namespaces(root1,root2):
   for prefix, uri in root1.nsmap.items():
      if prefix not in root2.nsmap.values():
         ET.register_namespace(prefix,uri)

 #Merge namespaces
 merge_namespaces(root1, root2)

 #Append elements from the second XML file to the first XML file
 for elem in root2:
     root1.append(elem)

 #Create a new ElementTree object with the merged root 
 merged_tree = ET.ElementTree(root1)

 #Write the merged XML to a new file 
 merged_tree.write('', encoding = 'utf-8', xml_declaration = True)

In the last step I do get the error AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'nsmap'
I think the problem is related the fact, that I try to convert str to bytes, but I don't know how to slove it.
I tried also to look at the file via trostring to get a better understanding, but the file is to big -> Javascript Error: too much recursion
Here is the sample for Wind:

Here is the sample for Netzanschlusspunkt:

In reality the files do have much more columns.

please correct your indentation. your loops are broken, it is hard to tell what your code is really doing

you're mixing lxml and xml.etree.ElementTree code. the latter indeed does not have nsmap attribute

Please insert your import statements. Which files have you selected? A dummy xml should be added for a minimal working example.

Why not solve this task with pandas. Here a proposal.
Read only what you need with iterparse() and concatenate the results to a new XML-File. Better write the content into a sqlite3 or other database, because this two files have still a huge number of rows!
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

# read only what you need - caution different xml have different columns!
list_of_value = ["LokationMaStRNummer", "NameDerTechnischenLokation","Lokationtyp","Spannungsebene","Nettoengpassleistung","BilanzierungsgebietNetzanschlusspunktId","NetzMaStRNummer","NochInPlanung"]

with zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\...yourPath\Gesamtdatenexport_20230401_22.2_e9dfe43b5f3d4b3cba437ca86729c43f.zip', 'r') as archive:
    # archive.printdir()
    
    # here you can use a loop, I made only a example here with two files to show the principle
    df1 = pd.read_xml(archive.open("Netzanschlusspunkte_1.xml"), iterparse={"Netzanschlusspunkt": list_of_value})
    # print(df1)
    df2 = pd.read_xml(archive.open("Netzanschlusspunkte_2.xml"), iterparse={"Netzanschlusspunkt": list_of_value})
    # print(df2)
    
    # write new XML
    df_sum = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
    df_sum.to_xml(r'C:\Users\...yourPath\Netzanschlusspunkte_concatenate.xml', root_name="Netzanschlusspunkte", row_name="Netzanschlusspunkt", index=False)
print("File written!!")

